Como puedo guardar una foto en galeria? .Net MAUI
He estado mirando y al parecer a partir de la versión 12 de Android cambian los permisos de gestión de ficheros y también de imágenes, por lo que pongo lo que pone en el documento de media picker.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

Estos permisos.
La cosa es que he visto que la gente lo almacena en el siguiente sitio
var photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

o
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

Pero te lo guarda dentro de la aplicación, cosa que en explorador de archivos no lo puedes ver y si borras el cache, borras la imagen.
¿Cómo podría guardarlo en la galeria del móvil creando un album o directorio?

La forma que he encontrado para guardar las fotos en la galería en un dispositivo Android es la siguiente:
 public static async Task SaveImage(Stream imageStream)
        {
            using var stream = imageStream;
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

            stream.Position = 0;
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

#if ANDROID
            var context = Platform.CurrentActivity;

            if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(29))
            {
                Android.Content.ContentResolver resolver = context.ContentResolver;
                Android.Content.ContentValues contentValues = new();
                contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.DisplayName, "image.png");
                contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.MimeType, "image/png");
                contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.RelativePath, "DCIM/" + "image");
                Android.Net.Uri imageUri = resolver.Insert(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, contentValues);

                var os = resolver.OpenOutputStream(imageUri);
                Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new();
                options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
                var bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
                bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
                os.Flush();
                os.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Java.IO.File storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.ToString(), "image.png");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, memoryStream.ToArray());
                var mediaScanIntent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path)));
                context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }

#endif
        }

-Se verifica si se está ejecutando en una versión de Android 29 o superior utilizando OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(29).
-Se crea un objeto ContentResolver para interactuar con el proveedor de contenido del dispositivo.
-Se crea un objeto ContentValues para especificar los metadatos de la imagen que se va a guardar.
-Se establecen los valores de los metadatos:
DisplayName: El nombre de la imagen (en este caso, "image.png").
MimeType: El tipo de MIME de la imagen (en este caso, "image/png").
RelativePath: La ruta relativa donde se guardará la imagen (en este caso, "DCIM/image").
-Se inserta la imagen en el proveedor de contenido utilizando resolver.Insert y se obtiene un objeto Uri que representa la ubicación de la imagen.
-Se abre un stream de salida para escribir la imagen en la ubicación especificada utilizando resolver.OpenOutputStream.
-Se crea un objeto BitmapFactory.Options para especificar las opciones de decodificación de la imagen.
-Se decodifica la imagen desde el stream original utilizando BitmapFactory.DecodeStream.
-Se comprime la imagen en formato PNG con una calidad del 100% utilizando bitmap.Compress.
-Se escribe la imagen comprimida en el stream de salida utilizando os.Flush y os.Close.

Hola Giorgio, bienvenido, me alegro que hayas encontrado la solución, te comento que las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, por lo que puedes recibir votos negativos, te sugiero que la edites, y expliques como tu código soluciona el problema planteado.

Para obtener la ruta, concatenarle un folder y asegurarte de ese folder existe o crearlo en el momento, puedes usar el siguiente código:
string ruta = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Pictures);
var miCarpeta = Path.Combine(ruta, "micarpeta");
if (!Directory.Exists(miCarpeta)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(miCarpeta);
}
string imgPath = Path.Combine(miCarpeta, photo.FileName);

Para Android 11 y superiores, debes asegurarte de pedir los permisos en tiempo de ejecución, además de tenerlos en el manifiesto, por ejemplo:
if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android && OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(30)) {
    var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Media>();

    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Media>();
    }

    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
        // El usuario no dio permisos!
        return;
    }
}

Más información en la documentación de la clase Permissions.

en .Net MAUI no encuentro un MediaLibrary solo mediaelement o media picker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.media?view=net-maui-8.0

Tienes razón, ahora actualizo la respuesta.

@Giorgio edité la respuesta. No tengo manera de probarla por ahora, si algo no compila o no funciona, por favor déjame un comentario. Saludos.

así funcionan los permisos gracias, pero el Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Pictures); me lo guarda dentro de la carpeta que crea la app, he actualizado la publicacion.

Amigo, tu pregunta original era sobre Android (según las etiquetas de la publicación. Si eso ya está superado, considera publicar una nueva pregunta para otro sistema operativo. La función de edición está diseñada para mejorar y perfeccionar la pregunta que se ha hecho, hasta que pueda ser respondida, no para cambiar de pregunta o seguir con cosas nuevas hasta completar un proyecto.

Entendido, Gracias.
